# Push notification is not working using parse.com android?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have created simple push notification app using parse.com.

devices registered successfully on parse.com but when i try to send push notification through parse.com no notification have come.

AndroidMainifest.xml Code:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.parse.starter" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="" />
```

Reciever Code:

```
    public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    private Intent parseIntent;

    public Receiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

        if (intent == null)
            return;

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

            parseIntent = intent;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("PushJsonException", "" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity Code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Parse.initialize(this);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Call Methods to Update Your Stuff
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.harrypotter.pushnotificationdemo"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);

    }
```

Application Class :

```
public class ParseApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use GCM service for push notification

Comment: Where is the Application Class?

Comment: I have put application class code

Comment: follow this tutorial for Push Notifications: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/

Answer (score 0):

Parse.com Hosted Service is fully retiring on January 28, 2017. If you have an existing application, refer to this [link](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App) and create your own push notification server. Parse release a database migration tool that lets you migrate data from your Parse app to any MongoDB database.

For More Information Check The [LInk](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/)

Answer (score 0):

You have not changed the Category attribute in your Manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".

```
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="YOUR PACKAGE NAME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
        android:value="" />
```